# Android fragment implementing Yahoo Finance quotes. App keeps crashing

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment, yahoo-finance

All I am trying to do is change my TextViews to the current price and change in percent of the S&P 500. For some reason my app keeps crashing though. I am new to fragments so I'm not sure if I am putting the code in the right place. Anyone have an ideas? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here is my code:

```
package com.capstone.hammond.wallstreetfantasyleaguefinal;

import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;
import org.apache.http.util.ByteArrayBuffer;
import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;

public class CurrentMarketTrendsFragment extends Fragment {
    TextView spPrice;
    TextView spPercent;

View rootview;

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    rootview = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_current_market_trends, container, false);
    return rootview;
}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

    spPrice = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.sp_price);
    spPercent = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.sp_percent);

    getQuotes();
}


public void getQuotes() {
    try {
        final String spSymbol = "^GSPC";
        List<String> results = new YahooFinanceTask().execute(spSymbol).get();
        setResult(results.get(0), results.get(1), results.get(2));
    } catch(InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch(ExecutionException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}


private void setResult(String fStockSymbol, String stockPrice, String fStockChangePercentage) {
    spPrice.setText(stockPrice);
    spPercent.setText(fStockChangePercentage);
}

public class YahooFinanceTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, List<String>> {
    @Override
    protected List<String> doInBackground(String... symbols) {
        try {
            URL url;
            try {
                url = new URL("http://download.finance.yahoo.com/quotes.csv?s=" + symbols[0] + "&f=nl1p2");

                InputStream stream = url.openStream();

                BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(stream);

                ByteArrayBuffer baf = new ByteArrayBuffer(50);

                int current = 0;

                while ((current = bis.read()) != -1) {
                    baf.append((byte) current);
                }

                String stockTxt = new String(baf.toByteArray());

                String[] tokens = stockTxt.split(",");

                String stockSymbol = tokens[0];
                String stockPrice = tokens[1];
                String stockChangePercentage = tokens[2];

                String fStockSymbol = stockSymbol.substring(1,
                        stockSymbol.length() - 1);
                String fStockChangePercentage = stockChangePercentage
                        .substring(1, stockChangePercentage.length() - 3);

                List<String> results = new ArrayList<String>();
                results.add(fStockSymbol);
                results.add(stockPrice);
                results.add(fStockChangePercentage);

                return results;


            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }

    }
}
```

}

Here is my logcat output:

```
04-20 13:44:46.779: E/AndroidRuntime(3213): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-20 13:44:46.779: E/AndroidRuntime(3213): Process: com.capstone.hammond.wallstreetfantasyleaguefinal, PID: 3213
04-20 13:44:46.779: E/AndroidRuntime(3213): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.capstone.hammond.wallstreetfantasyleaguefinal/com.capstone.hammond.wallstreetfantasyleaguefinal.NavDrawer}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'java.lang.Object java.util.List.get(int)' on a null object reference
04-20 13:44:46.779: E/AndroidRuntime(3213):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2298)
04-20 13:44:46.779: E/AndroidRuntime(3213):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360)
04-20 13:44:46.779: E/AndroidRuntime(3213):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
04-20 13:44:46.779: E/AndroidRuntime(3213):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278)
04-20 13:44:46.779: E/AndroidRuntime(3213):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
04-20 13:44:46.779: E/AndroidRuntime(3213):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
04-20 13:44:46.779: E/AndroidRuntime(3213):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
04-20 13:44:46.779: E/AndroidRuntime(3213):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
04-20 13:44:46.779: E/AndroidRuntime(3213):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
04-20 13:44:46.779: E/AndroidRuntime(3213):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
04-20 13:44:46.779: E/AndroidRuntime(3213):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
04-20 13:44:46.779: E/AndroidRuntime(3213): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'java.lang.Object java.util.List.get(int)' on a null object reference
04-20 13:44:46.779: E/AndroidRuntime(3213):     at com.capstone.hammond.wallstreetfantasyleaguefinal.CurrentMarketTrendsFragment.getQuotes(CurrentMarketTrendsFragment.java:52)
04-20 13:44:46.779: E/AndroidRuntime(3213):     at com.capstone.hammond.wallstreetfantasyleaguefinal.CurrentMarketTrendsFragment.onViewCreated(CurrentMarketTrendsFragment.java:44)
04-20 13:44:46.779: E/AndroidRuntime(3213):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:971)
04-20 13:44:46.779: E/AndroidRuntime(3213):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1136)
04-20 13:44:46.779: E/AndroidRuntime(3213):     at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:739)
04-20 13:44:46.779: E/AndroidRuntime(3213):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1499)
04-20 13:44:46.779: E/AndroidRuntime(3213):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:548)
04-20 13:44:46.779: E/AndroidRuntime(3213):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1220)
04-20 13:44:46.779: E/AndroidRuntime(3213):     at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:5949)
04-20 13:44:46.779: E/AndroidRuntime(3213):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261)
04-20 13:44:46.779: E/AndroidRuntime(3213):     ... 10 more
04-20 13:44:47.055: I/art(3213): Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 5528(543KB) AllocSpace objects, 2(32KB) LOS objects, 13% free, 4MB/4MB, paused 46.922ms total 268.858ms
04-20 13:44:47.254: W/ActivityManager(1246):   Force finishing activity com.capstone.hammond.wallstreetfantasyleaguefinal/.NavDrawer
04-20 13:44:47.271: E/gralloc_goldfish(932): gralloc_alloc: Mismatched usage flags: 576 x 576, usage 333
04-20 13:44:47.271: W/GraphicBufferAllocator(932): alloc(576, 576, 1, 00000333, ...) failed -22 (Invalid argument)
04-20 13:44:47.271: E/(932): GraphicBufferAlloc::createGraphicBuffer(w=576, h=576) failed (Invalid argument), handle=0x0
04-20 13:44:47.278: E/BufferQueueProducer(1246): [ScreenshotClient] dequeueBuffer: createGraphicBuffer failed
04-20 13:44:47.280: W/WindowManager(1246): Screenshot failure taking screenshot for (1080x1920) to layer 22015
04-20 13:44:47.280: E/ActivityManager(1246): Invalid thumbnail dimensions: 576x576
04-20 13:44:47.506: I/OpenGLRenderer(1246): Initialized EGL, version 1.4
04-20 13:44:47.607: W/EGL_emulation(1246): eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
04-20 13:44:47.608: W/OpenGLRenderer(1246): Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0x9e6ff120, error=EGL_SUCCESS
04-20 13:44:49.461: I/Choreographer(1246): Skipped 102 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
04-20 13:44:49.465: D/TaskPersister(1246): removeObsoleteFile: deleting file=465_task.xml
04-20 13:44:49.581: W/ActivityManager(1246): Activity pause timeout for ActivityRecord{2ead84f2 u0 com.capstone.hammond.wallstreetfantasyleaguefinal/.NavDrawer t466 f}
04-20 13:44:49.871: W/EGL_emulation(1519): eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
04-20 13:44:49.871: W/OpenGLRenderer(1519): Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xa3650b40, error=EGL_SUCCESS
04-20 13:44:52.559: W/OpenGLRenderer(1519): Incorrectly called buildLayer on View: ShortcutAndWidgetContainer, destroying layer...
04-20 13:44:52.559: W/OpenGLRenderer(1519): Incorrectly called buildLayer on View: ShortcutAndWidgetContainer, destroying layer...
04-20 13:44:52.559: W/OpenGLRenderer(1519): Incorrectly called buildLayer on View: ShortcutAndWidgetContainer, destroying layer...
04-20 13:45:00.044: I/ProcessStatsService(1246): Prepared write state in 4ms
04-20 13:45:02.220: W/ActivityManager(1246): Activity destroy timeout for ActivityRecord{2ead84f2 u0 com.capstone.hammond.wallstreetfantasyleaguefinal/.NavDrawer t466 f}
04-20 13:45:02.304: W/ActivityManager(1246): Activity destroy timeout for ActivityRecord{2fb205b6 u0 com.capstone.hammond.wallstreetfantasyleaguefinal/.LoginActivity t465 f}
04-20 13:45:02.348: W/SurfaceFlinger(932): couldn't log to binary event log: overflow.
04-20 13:45:05.745: D/TaskPersister(1246): removeObsoleteFile: deleting file=466_task.xml
```

So it is caused by a null pointer exception but I don't know why it would be getting that.

Comment: A first step would be to post your logcat of the crash.

Comment: post your logcat please

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can directly access what doInBackground returns as you are trying to do here

```
List<String> results = new YahooFinanceTask().execute(spSymbol).get();
```

You need to Override `onPostExecute` in your AsynsTask and call your `setResult` method there.

```
@Override
    protected void onPostExecute(List<String> results) {
        super.onPostExecute(results);

       setResult(results.get(0), results.get(1), results.get(2));

    }
```

Then execute the AsyncTask in your `onViewCreated`

```
@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

   spPrice = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.sp_price);
   spPercent = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.sp_percent);

   final String spSymbol = "^GSPC";
   new YahooFinanceTask().execute(spSymbol);

 }
```

Comment: Are you sure your results in the async gets any data? Have you tried logging out its contents? Oh and just Before the last catch block in your code, You're returning null, could be a potential problem